# I want to override in typoscript CONTENT or renderObj with noting

Tags: typo3, overriding, typoscript

I have a little problem, the following code works, but to not show what I do not want to display, I'm forced to put `style =" display: none "` with invalid HTML code, because I'm in `<ul> <li> ... </ ul>`. How could I not display anything at all?

```
40 = CONTENT
40 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        pidInList.field = uid
        where = {#colPos}=99  and deleted = 0 and hidden = 0
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        20 = TEXT
        20.stdWrap.field = header
        20.stdWrap.wrap = <b>|</b>

        # OVERRIDE for <ul><li> ...
        20.stdWrap.wrap.override = <span style="display:none">|</span>                        
        20.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.value = 1
        20.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}   

        30 = TEXT
        30.stdWrap.field = bodytext
        30.stdWrap.wrap = <i>|</i>

        # OVERRIDE for <ul><li> ...                             
        30.stdWrap.wrap.override = <span style="display:none">|</span>                         
        30.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.value = 1
        30.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}   

        40 = FILES
        40 {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                uid.data = field:uid
                fieldName = image
            }
            begin = 0
            maxItems = 1

            renderObj = IMAGE
            renderObj {
                file {
                    import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
                    #width = 232c
                    #height = 145c
                }
                required = 1
                wrap = <div class="img-wrap">|</div>
            }
        }

        # OVERRIDE for <ul><li> ...
        40.stdWrap.wrap.override = <span style="display:none">|</span>
        40.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.value = 1
        40.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}                         
    }//COA
}//CONTENT
```

In fact, I tried a lot of stuff before resigning myself to `<span style =" display: none "> | </ span>`, do you have a better solution?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these propositions?

```
40.renderObj.40.if {
    value = 1
    equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}
}
```

or

```
40.renderObj.40.stdWrap.if {
    value = 1
    equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}
}
```

if that's not working you've to check if the register is filled with any data, you can check that just by rendering it too in `40.renderObj.50`:

```
40.renderObj.50 = TEXT
40.renderObj.50.data = {register:typeOfMenu}
```

As it seems that `{register:typeOfMenu}` is defined outside that `CONTENT` and you want to render the whole block only if `{register:typeOfMenu}=1` you could also note it like this:

```
40 = CONTENT
40 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
       orderBy = sorting
       pidInList.field = uid
       where = {#colPos}=99  and deleted = 0 and hidden = 0
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
       20 = TEXT
       20.stdWrap.field = header
       20.stdWrap.wrap = <b>|</b>

       30 = TEXT
       30.stdWrap.field = bodytext
       30.stdWrap.wrap = <i>|</i>

       40 = FILES
       40 {
           references {
               table = tt_content
               uid.data = field:uid
               fieldName = image
           }
           begin = 0
           maxItems = 1
           renderObj = IMAGE
           renderObj {
               file {
                   import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
                   #width = 232c
                   #height = 145c
               }
               required = 1
               wrap = <div class="img-wrap">|</div>
            }
        }
    }//COA
    stdWrap.if {
        value = 1
        equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}
    }
}//CONTENT
```

Comment: In fact, my typoscript code works, but it is not elegant and in addition it introduces `<span style =" display: none ">foo ...</ span>` to places that make the HTML code invalid (the `{register: typeOfMenu}` variable exists and is well initialized). I tried your proposals but no, it does not work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why so complicated? for `.if.equals` you can use `.data = register:typeOfMenu` directly. no tampering with `.dataWrap`. You also may try to skip the `.stdWrap` as `CONTENT` should accept `.if` immideately.

Comment: Right, or the whole block in a condition

Comment: It's not good, but I simplified the writing a bit by doing after the `CONTENT`: `40.stdWrap.wrap.override = <span style = "display: none">|</ span>` then `40.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.value = 1` and then `40.stdWrap.wrap.override.if.equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}` but it's still not clean. But for now a little better. The tests you offer do not work. You know, I do not want `CONTENT` to appear when the variable `register:typeOfMenu` is at 1.

Comment: If you note your TypoScript in a referenced file you've to clear the cache each time you change something

Comment: Hello no cache problem ... `no_cache=1` in the Whole Template Record.

Comment: Is it possible that the TS is then still overriden in another location? Slowly I get the impression the applied TS-rules never work like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I did not put all the code, there was before a `COA`. Now, thanks to your advice I have solved the problem. Here is the complete code:

```
      NO {
        doNotLinkIt = 1

        stdWrap.cObject = COA
        stdWrap.cObject {            
            10 = TEXT
            10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
            10.field = nav_title // title
            10.typolink.parameter.field = uid

            # OVERRIDE for <ul><li> ...
            10.wrap.override = <li class="laclasse">|
            10.wrap.override.if.value = 1
            10.wrap.override.if.equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}

            40 = CONTENT
            40 {
                table = tt_content
                select {
                    orderBy = sorting
                    pidInList.field = uid
                    where = {#colPos}=99  and deleted = 0 and hidden = 0
                }

                renderObj = COA
                renderObj {
                    20 = TEXT
                    20.stdWrap.field = header
                    20.stdWrap.wrap = <b>|</b>  

                    30 = TEXT
                    30.stdWrap.field = bodytext
                    30.stdWrap.wrap = <i>|</i>

                    40 = FILES
                    40 {
                        references {
                            table = tt_content
                            uid.data = field:uid
                            fieldName = image
                        }
                        begin = 0
                        maxItems = 1

                        renderObj = IMAGE
                        renderObj {
                            file {
                                import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
                                #width = 232c
                                #height = 145c
                            }
                            required = 1
                            #wrap = <div class="img-wrap">|</div>

                            titleText.data = page:subtitle
                            altText.data = page:subtitle
                            stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = leveluid:0                                
                            }
                        }                        
                }//COA
            }//CONTENT
        }//COA

        # OVERRIDE for <ul><li> ...
        stdWrap.cObject.40.if {                    
                value = 1
                equals.dataWrap = {register:typeOfMenu}
                negate = 1
        }
```

Thanking you,
Best regards